What RU4 mean in gstreamer document

"RGB" RGB

       +--+--+--+ +--+--+--+
       |R0|G0|B0| |R1|G1|B1| ...
       +--+--+--+ +--+--+--+

        Component 0: R
          depth:           8
          pstride:         3
          offset:          0

        Component 1: G
          depth:           8
          pstride:         3
          offset:          1

        Component 2: B
          depth            8
          pstride:         3
          offset:          2

        Image
          default rstride: RU4 (width * 3)
          default size:    rstride (image) * height

Above is the format of RGB format. But I don't understand it.
I have got a GstBuffer with RGB format. And debug it with its information:
auto caps = gst_sample_get_caps(sample);
GstVideoFrame cuda_frame;
GstVideoInfo info;
gst_video_info_from_caps(&info, caps);
gst_video_frame_map(&cuda_frame, &info, buffer, (GstMapFlags) (GST_MAP_READ | GST_MAP_CUDA));
spdlog::debug("n components: {}, n plane: {}, frame size: {}, frame width: {}, frame height: {}",
    GST_VIDEO_FRAME_N_COMPONENTS(&cuda_frame),
    GST_VIDEO_FRAME_N_PLANES(&cuda_frame),
    GST_VIDEO_FRAME_SIZE(&cuda_frame),
    GST_VIDEO_FRAME_WIDTH(&cuda_frame),
    GST_VIDEO_FRAME_HEIGHT(&cuda_frame)
);
for (size_t i = 0; i < GST_VIDEO_FRAME_N_COMPONENTS(&cuda_frame); i++)
{
    spdlog::debug("[component {}] depth: {}, width: {}, height: {}, offset: {}, stride: {}, plane: {}, poffset: {}, pstride: {}",
        i,
        GST_VIDEO_FRAME_COMP_DEPTH(&cuda_frame, i),
        GST_VIDEO_FRAME_COMP_WIDTH(&cuda_frame, i),
        GST_VIDEO_FRAME_COMP_HEIGHT(&cuda_frame, i),
        GST_VIDEO_FRAME_COMP_OFFSET(&cuda_frame, i),
        GST_VIDEO_FRAME_COMP_STRIDE(&cuda_frame, i),
        GST_VIDEO_FRAME_COMP_PLANE(&cuda_frame, i),
        GST_VIDEO_FRAME_COMP_POFFSET(&cuda_frame, i),
        GST_VIDEO_FRAME_COMP_PSTRIDE(&cuda_frame, i)
    );
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < GST_VIDEO_FRAME_N_PLANES(&cuda_frame); i++)
{
    spdlog::debug("[plane {}] offset: {}, stride: {}",
        i,
        GST_VIDEO_FRAME_PLANE_OFFSET(&cuda_frame, i),
        GST_VIDEO_FRAME_PLANE_STRIDE(&cuda_frame, i)
    );
}

n components: 3, n plane: 1, frame size: 150528, frame width: 224, frame height: 224
[component 0] depth: 8, width: 224, height: 224, offset: 0, stride: 1024, plane: 0, poffset: 0, pstride: 3
[component 1] depth: 8, width: 224, height: 224, offset: 1, stride: 1024, plane: 0, poffset: 1, pstride: 3
[component 2] depth: 8, width: 224, height: 224, offset: 2, stride: 1024, plane: 0, poffset: 2, pstride: 3

Can some explain what RU4 means here.
And what pstride and rstride are?
I known componet mean channel, such as R, G, B. But what does offset, stride, plane, poffset and pstride of component mean?
I think my buffer size should be 224 * 224 * 3 = 150528. The frame size is really 150528. But the buffer size is 224 * 224 * 4 = 229376. Why?

pstride is the pixel stride I believe. It is 3 so one pixel occupies 3 bytes (R, G and B).
The stride is the size in bytes per row. It is 1024. That means each pixel row occupies 1024 bytes in total.
For a width of 224 that means the pixel data for that row takes up 224 x 3 = 672 bytes. The row stride is 1024, which means after 672 bytes used the row has 1024 - 672 = 352 bytes left.
These 352 bytes contain no image data (and probably no useful data at all). So each row basically starts at each stride-value's boundaries.
P.S. 224×224×4 = 200704. I would expect your buffer to be stride x height so 1024 * 224 = 229376.

How do I verify this conjecture? I can print the pixels to text, but obviously to a human it's just meaningless gibberish, is there any tool to convert it to an image? Also what does RU4 mean? I googled half a dozen times and all the results are unrelated. Why do people always like to use abbreviations that don't make sense~?

RU4 probably means rounded up to a multiple of 4. You have raw RGB data. You would have to write it to a file with appropriate headers of the file format you want it to be. There are also raw video viewer applications out there.

but 224 x 3 = 672 has been a multiple of 4

That would be the default, yes. But some component (some graphics hardware most likely) defined a stride requirement of 1024.

I have validate it by opencv, Your guess of layout is correct. But I stll want to known the meaning of RUN (RU2, RU4) in the document. With out understanding the meaning of it, I can't understand the layout of the video formats listed in the document.
